# Get records from related entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a list of Keyword ids: {1,2,3,4}

Keyword entity:

```
public class Keyword
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Ad> Ads { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of Ads that have each a set of Keywords:

```
public class Ad
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Keyword> Keywords { get; set; }
}
```

How can I get the Ad Id's that match ALL the list of Keyword ids ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `keywords` is an array of keyword id´s you search for and `allAds` is a list of all ads to search through:

```
var keywords = new[]{1,2,3,4};
List<Ad> allAds = new List<Ad>();
```

the following statement should find all ads that have all required keywords:

```
var matchingAds = allAds.Where(ad => 
        keywords.All(keyword => 
            ad.Keywords.Any(x => x.Id == keyword)
        )
    );
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I get the error "ad.Keywords does not contain a definition for Any :(

Comment: @Patrick You are probably missing `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keywords = new[]{1,2,3,4};

var query = Keywords.Where(kw => keywords.Any(n => n == kw.Id))
                    .SelectMany(m => m.Ads)
                    .Select(n => n.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. In the meantime I found a way to do it, and I tried to compare with yours regarding speed, but they seem very similar, what do you think? Mine is: var adIds = adQuery.Where(ad => keywordIds.All(k => ad.Keywords.Select(kw => kw.Id).Contains(k))).Select(ad => ad.Id);

Comment: hi @Patrick, These two queries are not same, also they'll give you different results. Because you're using "keywords.All(k => ad.Keywords.Select(kw => kw.Id).Contains(k)))", I think you should use keywords.Any() are not keyworkds.All(). What do you think?